# Ajax call every 5 seconds (flicker issue)

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, call

I'm using the following jQuery which works:

```
setInterval(function() { 
  $.ajax({
    url: 'helper.php',
    type: 'GET',
    data: 'ckc=1&user_token=<?php echo $user_token; ?>',
    dataType: 'html'
  }).done(function(data) {
    console.log(data); 
    $('#tag_f').html(data); 
  });
}, 5000);
```

However after 20 minutes the browser page starts to flicker every time a call is made. Is there a cleaner way of doing this every 5 seconds? And for it not to appear on the console?

Basically this call checks the MYSQL database if there have been any changes.

Comment: AJAX polling is a bad idea, not least due to the memory issues it can have when the page is open for a long period (which I'd guess is your issue here). I'd strongly suggest you look in to using WebSockets or Server Sent Events instead, as they are much better suited for keeping the server-side data and the UI in sync

Comment: Also, re. your comment about the AJAX request not appearing in the console, no that's not possible.

Comment: Ahh thank you!...I shall look into WebSockets, if possible would you be able to give me example code using Websockets? so i can adapt my script above??

Comment: There's a few examples in the [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket), however you should note that you will need to refactor your server logic to support sockets, though. Exactly how you do that will depend on what technology you use on the server.

Comment: Not sure which part of console logging you are referring to but you could remove `console.log(data);` to not log the data